# nvidia-cuda-toolkit and nvidia driver version

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I have Ubuntu 16.04 with nvidia GeForce 9800GT. The default driver is nvidia-340 and it works well.

However, the problem begins when I want to install the "nvidia-cuda-toolkit" package to utilize CUDA tools. The installer wants to remove nvidia-340 and to install the newest nvidia-381 driver.

I tried it : the nvidia-381 driver causes shrinked screen borders and infinite login loop. So I rather decided to remove nvidia-cuda-toolkit and returned to stable nvidia-340.

Any help concerning mixing nvidia-381 and ubuntu 16.04+GeForce 9800GT ? 
Does nvidia-381 support such old graphics cards ?

PS: The libcuda1-340 package provides cuda tools and is consistent with nvidia-340. Fine then.

Comment: If you think you found a solution, you could post it as your own answer. It is [explicitly encouraged](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Closing this issue as the nvidia-340 driver is the only one working for GeForce 9800GT. As I checked on their web-page, newer drivers do not support old graphics cards like mine.